# App logs on production

Tags: codenameone

We are looking for logs or exception logs for app on device, on this I came to know how to handle exception by the following url [Handling the exception in Codename one](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/handling-the-exception.html)

Here my question where we need to consider the following code to get the logs information

```
Display.getInstance().addEdtErrorHandler(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    evt.consume();
    Log.p("Exception in AppName version " + 
            Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "Unknown"));
    Log.p("OS " + Display.getInstance().getPlatformName());
    Log.p("Error " + evt.getSource());
    Log.p("Current Form " + Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getName());
    Log.e((Throwable)evt.getSource());
    Log.sendLog();
}
```

});

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking, this code is triggered when an error occurs on the EDT. Notice, the sendLog feature is available for pro subscriptions

Comment: Chen, You mean to say this code called internally to throw the alert on EDT?

Comment: Yes, if an Error occurs on the EDT this listener is invoked